# In Highcharts, are we able to make the border of a pyramid in 'dashed' style?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm wondering if we could make a dashed border for a pyramid chart.
Dashed border isn't native supported by Highcharts, but for column/bar chart, I've found a simple extension to make it happen:
`Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.pointAttrToOptions.dashstyle = 'dashStyle';`
But for a pyramid chart, I can't find a similar way to do that.
Is there any way we could make the border of a pyramid 'dashed'?
Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/18009rf1/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `chart.load` event, you can loop over each point, call attr() on graphic element and apply the dashStyle param.

```
  events:{
    load:function() {
        var chart = this,
          series = chart.series[0],
          each = Highcharts.each;

      each(series.data, function(p, d) {
        p.graphic.attr({
          dashstyle: 'Dash'
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/0p62up21/

DashStyles:

```
    'Solid',
    'ShortDash',
    'ShortDot',
    'ShortDashDot',
    'ShortDashDotDot',
    'Dot',
    'Dash',
    'LongDash',
    'DashDot',
    'LongDashDot',
    'LongDashDotDot'
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/xccct7k7/

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Bochan! This is fantastic!